# Features from a Team Foundation Server 2010 installation were detected

Tags: tfs

Error : TF400543 : Features from a Team Foundation Server 2010 installation were detected.  To continue with this installation or upgrade, you must uninstall the previous version.  See the setup guide for additional information.

I uninstalled old version of tfs2010 but still showing the above error message ... please anybody can help???

Answer (score 1):

You have installed sharepoint extension and you haven't delete, i suggest you to delete registry key

```
[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\TeamFoundationServer\10.0\InstalledComponents\SharePointExtensions]
```